# Bash script that will execute a program over all files in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Writing  a bash script that will execute the program 'main' over all the files in the directory 'allfiles'. Main is an executable. The results are then directed to the file 'output.dat'.

Whenever I run the bash script I get the error "./main: no such file or directory". The bash script, main, and 'allfiles' directory are all in the '/home/directory/'. I'm not certain as to why i'm getting this error, or if i'm writing the bash script correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /home/directory/allfiles/*
do
   ./main $file >> output.dat
done
```

edit: should clarify that 'main' is an executable file produced from a makefile

Comment: If `main` is correctly written, it should be able to run all files with `./main /home/directory/allfiles/*` directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not in `/home/directory` when you run the script, then it won't be able to find main.  Try

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /home/directory/allfiles/*
do
   /home/directory/main $file >> output.dat
done
```

Additionally, if main is not executable, you'll have to get bash to call it manually.  Use `bash /home/directory/main $file` for that, or make main executable using `chmod +x main`.

Comment: Sorry I should have made that more clear, I am in the /home/directory/ when running the script

Comment: Updated answer, for the other possible problem

Comment: Again sorry for not stating this originally, main is an executable that was produced from a makefile

Comment: If main is in the directory you're in when you run your script, and if it is executable (ls -l will check this), and if your script doesn't change directories, then it will execute, without the "./main: no such file or directory" message.  Can you double-check all those bits?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using find in this case of use. You can manage using subdirs ;)

```
#!/bin/bash
main=./main
basedir=/home/directory/allfiles/
outFile=output.dat

for file in $(find $basedir -type f)
do
    $main $file >> $outFile
done
```